# Illustrator file to single word Dataset

Tags: dataset, tensorflow-datasets

I have an Illustrator file containing multiple-line text, and I want to segment it into words. Each word will be saved as an image, and all images will be saved in a folder.

Could you please suggest the correct way to do this?
I planned to build a new dataset for my research project but didn't know how to start.